# Find the number of times matched values between 2 pandas dataframes appear and display individual and total count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that look like the following:

df1

```
name    id    prob_val   chrom    pos    sample_name 
snp    chr_1_xx    0.001    chr1   10001    du11j
snp    chr_1_xx    0.00008    chr1   1199288    dj112
snp    chr_2_yy    0.0005   chr2   120000    xhh11
snp    chr_8_zz    1e-10    chr8   818277    yzm11
```

df2

```
name id    prob_val   chrom    pos    sample_name 
indel    chr_1_xx    0.00001    chr1   8827192    m43zh
indel    chr_2_yy    1e-10   chr2   7727881    ljhh12
indel    chr_9_rr    1e-10    chr8   1223334    suh18
```

I am trying to find the number of times the same id appear and has prob_val less than 1.0 in both Dataframes. Each name (snp or indel) will have different counting and I want to display that information too. For example, the desire output will be a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
name    id    count_snp   count_indel   total_count 
snp    chr_1_xx    2      1              3
snp    chr2_yy     1      1              2
```

I attempt this but I am having trouble incorporating the individual name count:

```
df1, df2 = all_dfs
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='id')
df = df[(df['prob_val_x'] < 1) & (df['prob_val_y'] < 1)] 
df = df.groupby(['id']).count().reset_index()
```

Updated code:

```
 id_in_df1 = df1[df1.id.isin(df2.id)]
 id_in_df2 = df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)]
 id_in_df1[id_in_df1['prob_val'] < 1].groupby(['id']).count().reset_index().nlargest(20, 'sample_name'))
```

How do I solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the dataframe code so we can copy and execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to count values from both data frames, you should concatenate data frames instead of merge; To only consider ids that appear in both data frames, you can pre-filter the data frames before concatenate and summarize:

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1.id.isin(df2.id) & (df1['prob_val'] < 1), ['name', 'id']]
df2 = df2.loc[df2.id.isin(df1.id) & (df2['prob_val'] < 1), ['name', 'id']]

df = df1.append(df2).groupby(['name', 'id']).size().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)

df
#name      indel  snp  total
#id                         
#chr_1_xx      1    2      3
#chr_2_yy      1    1      2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I got NaNs on the indel column.

Comment: NaN means for the specific id, there are no indel. You can specify `fill_value=0` in `unstack` to replace `NaN` with 0.

Comment: There number that shouldn't be NaN or filled with 0. If I do this for instance, "df1[df1['prob_val'] < 1].groupby(['id']).count().reset_index().nlargest(20, 'id'), I got different number than when I ran your code with the same matching ids.

Comment: Shouldn't it be different ? Your code doesn't take `df2` into account ?

Comment: Out of curiosity what if I have three dataframes, how that be solved ?